# Integer points on genus 1 curves using CAS

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, computer-algebra

How can I practically find integer points on genus 1 curves with small coefficients using computer algebra systems (CAS), like Mathematica, Maple, SageMath, Magma, etc.?

As a specific example, do there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
x^3+x^2y-y^3-y+3 = 0 ?
$$

As noted in the previous Mathoverflow question [Integer points of an elliptic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6676/integer-points-of-an-elliptic-curve) (and in the comments to this question) there is a paper

Stroeker and de Weger's "Solving elliptic diophantine equations: The general cubic case."

(see also Stroeker, Roel, and Nikolaus Tzanakis. "Computing all integer solutions of a genus 1 equation." Mathematics of computation 72.244 (2003): 1917-1933. for higher degree equations)

that describes the algorithm, but the details are quite non-trivial to work out by hand, especially because I need to solve many equations in this form.

Interestingly, in the more difficult case of genus 2 equations there is a Magma code, see e.g.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2700512/is-x5x5-y2-solvable-over-the-integers/2700727

and

[Find all rational solutions of $x^2(x+1)(x^2+1)(x-1)=2(y+1)(y-1)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256086/find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2x1x21x-1-2y1y-1)

that, for many specific equations (although not in general) able to automatically find all rational (and therefore all integer) solutions. Hence, it is a bit surprise for me that integer points on genus 1 curve (including Elliptic curve given by cubic equation in non-Weierstrass form) turned out to be more difficult for implementation.

(Remark: The question has been revised in the light of comments of
Chris Wuthrich that you can find below).

Comment: You must be aware that your question is a duplicate of the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6676/integer-points-of-an-elliptic-curve .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer points of an elliptic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6676/integer-points-of-an-elliptic-curve)

Comment: I am aware of that question, and my question is not a duplicate but rather follow up. That question is about elliptic curves, and the first part of my question is how to check that a given genus 1 equation has rational point and is therefore an elliptic curve. The second part of my question is about non-Weierstrass form.

Comment: Ok, I see, the second part is exactly what was asked in the other question (including non-Weierstrass) and the answer by Franz Lemmermayer and the link to Stroeker and de Weger's "Solving elliptic diophantine equations: The general cubic case." answers that question. I would rather want to see someone adding answers to the old question if there is more to say about it than answering here.

Comment: To your first question. If there is a local obstruction for the existence of a rational point on your genus 1 curve, then you are done. If there are no local obstructions and you have searched for a while, then you will have problems deciding if there is a point and even more for finding one. You could calculate (by p-adic methods or Heegner points) the Tate-Shafarevich group of the Jacobian and that might tell you that there must be a point.

Comment: Ex: $x^4 - y^2 + y - 3 = 0$ has two rational points at infinity. Using one of them it is isomorphic to its Jacobian $Y^2=X^3+11X$. That has exactly two rational points, so there are no $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ that satisfy your equation.